# How to run a script in python on multiple time series?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to run the following script using [the StatsModels library](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/):

```
cadf = ts.adfuller(df1.spread)
print 'Augmented Dickey Fuller test statistic =',cadf[0]
print 'Augmented Dickey Fuller p-value =',cadf[1]
print 'Augmented Dickey Fuller 1%, 5% and 10% test statistics =',cadf[4]
```

on my Data frame , my data-frame currently comprises of multiple time series (200+) , and I would like to run the above script on every time series . Below is an example of the dataframe :

```
Sn.No   A-B      B-C         A-C
  1       10       11.15       13.22
  2       11       12.36       14.75
  3       10.75    11.54       14.21
```

So , I would like to run the ADF test script on A-B,B-C and A-C and get the test statistic/output for each of them .

Comment: What statistics library are you using?

Comment: Hey man.  Using the statsmodel library

Comment: I thought so. Try to include any libraries in your questions. Makes it a bit easier to answer.

Comment: Will do thanks.  Kinda new to stack and Python so.

Comment: Welcome! :) No worries. I added it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access columns individually, instead of the entire data frame, basically:

```
df1['A-B']
```

will get you the first column. Round them up in a list:

```
columns = ['A-B', 'B-C', 'A-C']
```

If you have 200+ columns you should access them differently. Let's say you have 200. Something like this should be possible:

```
columns = range(200)
```

In that case you don't need the `xrange` function below, but like so:

```
df1.iloc(column)
```

The reason I know this is because I looked up [the source code for dataframe in the statmodels library](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dataframe), which apparently is a [Pandas dataframe](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). Assuming you have to enter the spread as in the above example, gather the output statistics in a
    list using a list comprehension expression.

```
cadfs = [ts.adfuller(df1[column].spread) for column in columns]
```

Instead, if you are accessing by numerical index:

```
cadfs = [ts.adfuller(df1.iloc(column).spread) for column in columns]
```

To make the code more
    readable use local constants.

```
TEST = 0    
P = 1
PERCENTILES = 4

values = [cadfs[column][TEST] for column in xrange(columns)]
ps     = [cadfs[column][P] for column in xrange(columns)]
pct    = [cadfs[column][PERCENTILES] for column in xrange(columns)]

print 'Augmented Dickey Fuller Test'
print 'ADF Test Statistics - p - Percentiles 1%, 5% and 10%'
print values, ps, pct
```

Comment: Hi Noumenal ,using the above logic , i wrote the code but i am encountering an error , i am attaching a img with the code and error , would be extremly helpful if you could guide me regarding it . [link](http://imgur.com/SRgUK7A)

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening, but it seems that x is not defined or that its shape has no length.